# playing multiple sounds(mp3, wav etc) in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

This is my requirement. I have set of audio files(mp3, wav mostly). My app's interface will have a list of these sound names and a toggle ON/OFF switch for each of the sound item. On switching a sound ON it should start playing and vice versa. If more than one sound is ON then they should be played simultaneously. I can switch any sound ON/OFF while the sound is playing  and it should switch off instantly.

What classes are best suggested for this behavior ? Do I need to mix the sounds etc or just instantiate multiple AVAudioPlayer instances ???

Please guide me in making an efficient app.

Thanks!

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is your best bet. You'll have to create multiple instances if you wanna play it simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Use `different` `instance` of `AVAudioPlayer` for playing simultaneously.

Now `maintain list` of `AVAudioPlayer` instance into `NSMutableArray` depending on `state ON/OFF`. if state `ON` then `play audio` `add AVAudioPlayer` instance in `array` and if state `OFF` then `stop audio` `remove AVAudioPlayer` instance from `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can user openAL to do your task. Here is the link to get it https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone .